# Why is json response NULL when I send video file larger than 20MB via POST?

Tags: ios, post, json

I am creating a POST request and using it to send a video to the  server. On the server side, I decode the video, and save it to a file directory. IF the video sent is under 20MB everything works as expected and I get a valid JSON response, otherwise my response dictionary is NULL or returns "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

```
    $result = mysqli insert statement;

$videoDirectory = 'userVideos/'.$unique_id.'.mp4';
    $decodedVideo =base64_decode($video);


    file_put_contents($videoDirectory, $decodedVideo);

    if (!$result['error']) 
    {
     $e = "register into Str33trider successfully";
     print json_encode(array('results'=>$videoCaption));
     exit();

    }
```

I've even edited my apache config file

```
   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 320M
   php_value max_file_uploads 200M
   php_value max_execution_time 30000
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
   </IfModule>
```

Comment: Looks like you've altered the .htaccess settings, what about the settings in the php.ini could that be killing you?

Comment: Checked my settings via phpinfo says upload_max_filesize 200M. Is there anything else in php.ini I should look for?

Comment: I suspect the time of base64_decode is taking too long for the larger videos but I'm not sure :(

Comment: What does this have to do with iOS? What do you mean with "json response is NULL"? Do you possibly mean the body data in the HTTP POST  request is empty?

Comment: The dictionary in the json response for the request is NULL, or I get the following response: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: The code works fine if the video is under 20mb

Comment: So, after sending the POST request you get a response from the server whose body is JSON or NULL, and parsing the JSON with NSJSONSerialization returns an NSError: Cocoa error 3840. Is this correct? What is the status code of the HTTP response? Where is your code? And could you please paraphrase your question to make it clear?

Comment: My response is either null, or returns  Cocoa error 3840. I have edited my question and my code, status code is 200 both times

Comment: Cocoa error 3840 will be returned from NSJSONSerialization. Do you anywhere parse the JSON? Where is the code?

Comment: Status code 200 (OK) means success. This would mean that the server did receive the large video data and processed it successfully. You may confirm that this is actually the case on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive a response for a POST request, first check the status code.

#### If the POST request succeeded:

If status code equals 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) the response body is likely empty or it describes the result of the operation. With either status codes, the request hasn't created a resource which can be identified by a URI.

If status code equals 201 (Created) the request created a resource on the server and the response body may describe the result of the operation, and the response should contain a location header where the new resource can be located.

Usually, the web service API describes the details about the response body (if any) and its content type and character encoding. Possibly, there are more than one format that can be send, e.g. JSON or XML.

#### If the POST request failed:

The server will send a corresponding status code and optionally a response body containing details about the error. Oftentimes, the server may send a response body in a content type which does not match the Accept header of the request.

#### Note:

A client should always also check the content type of the response body (if any) and decode it accordingly. In case of server errors, the content type may often be text/html instead in the content type specified in the Accept header, e.g. application/json.

So, if you log the complete error description for Cocoa error 3840 you will read that the given text is likely not JSON since it must start either with a '['  or '{'. This indicates, that you got an error message from the server which is not JSON. Decode the error message so that it is human readable and log it to the console to see what the server is telling you.

Comment: OK, the AFJSONREquestOperation fails but operation status code is still 200.  I dont know why it fails. Thanks Ill try and find out whats happening.

Comment: If I comment this line out I always get a valid response file_put_contents($videoDirectory, $decodedVideo);

Comment: AFJSONRequestOperation _expects_ JSON as response. Thus, it's not that suitable when your response is somewhat "nonchalant" to what you expect. Your web service behavior may also not be correct. Use a lower level class of AFNetworking or just implement your POST request directly with NSURLConnection, and decode the response depending on the Content-Type of the response.